# logging in ActiveMQ: when client application connects to standalone broker

Tags: java, spring, activemq-classic

I am running ActiveMQ 5.15.5 as a standalone broker and my spring application is connecting to it.
I am trying to trace the lifetime of a message in the client application log.

That is, in my application's `onMessage(Message p_message)` method I have different log statements which 
get printed under the thread ID: "ActiveMQ Session Task". 
Like below:

```
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,642 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationServiceImpl - ===>  START: dehydrate 
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,642 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationDaoImpl - ==> START: countCor 
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,649 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationDaoImpl - ==> END: countCor 
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,649 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationDaoImpl - ==> START: purge for id = 82559 
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,664 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationDaoImpl - ==> END: purge 
[INFO ] 2018-11-27 16:29:57,664 [ActiveMQ Session Task] HydrationServiceImpl - ==> END: dehydrate
```

So if more than 1 message is being worked on then all get the same thread ID:- [ActiveMQ Session Task]

Thus there is no way for me to categorize the **logs** for different messages.

Is there a way to be able to tell, for which message is the log statement for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Most logging frameworks implement something called a Mapped Diagnostic Context (MDC hereafter) to deal with situations like there where multiple threads are operating on individual pieces of work simultaneously. In short, the MDC allows you to push ID information onto a per-thread stack which you can then reference from your logging configuration. In your situation you could push the message ID onto the MDC, and then reference that from your logging configuration so that it's printed on all your log statements.

[Here's a decent article](https://dzone.com/articles/mdc-better-way-of-logging-1) about it.

Comment: so seems like MDC can solve my problem. thanks for that solution!